# Merge timeseries data over multiple lines by start and end into one

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got a DataFrame that looks like this

```
|Start   |End     |Description|Value|
|--------|--------|-----------|-----|
|01:02:00|01:05:00|A          |1.0  |
|01:05:00|01:08:00|A          |4.0  |
|01:08:00|01:11:00|A          |4.3  |
|01:11:00|01:15:00|B          |18.2 |
|01:21:00|01:55:00|C          |0.0  |
|01:55:00|02:07:00|A          |1.8  |
```

Now my goal is to use spark to combine all periods, which basically belong to one big period, back together, like this:

```
|Start   |End     |Description|Value(SUM)|
|--------|--------|-----------|----------|
|01:02:00|01:11:00|A          |9.3       |
|01:11:00|01:15:00|B          |18.2      |
|01:21:00|01:55:00|C          |0.0       |
|01:55:00|02:07:00|A          |1.8       |
```

So, to somehow put that in words:
I want to merge two lines if the start equals to the previous end and if the description is the same.

The issue I got is that I need to somehow create some kind of a window which contains coherent data, but ends as soon as there's a different description or the last end time isn't equal to the next start time

I think I cannot just use a groupby over the description and do some aggregations afterwards, because it misses context(coherent start/end) of the lines.

I already tried a solution using lead and lag, and I successfully merged the periods, but I was not able to take care of the value (and it also seemed like quite a complex operation for a simple task).

Is there a function or method to archive that (in a better way)?
It seems to be like quite a common process for time series data, but I cant find any resources related to that.

Comment: I updated the question DataFrame because I forgot a case (last line). Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it won't work then, does it?

Comment: you would need a udaf for that

Comment: @RameshMaharjan can you give me a hint how that might look like? My issue is that a udf needs somehow to be aware of the previous line, and I'm not sure how I can archive this.

Comment: use lag or lead with partition on description... and then compare it

Comment: The issue with lead/lag & comparison is that I can't aggregate the value over the whole period

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html and https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/spark-custom-udaf-example/ should give you a good start  and I am talking about udaf not udf

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Sorry, I misread that. I will take a look at that, thank you!